# Flex change color values in skin with something like ResourceManager

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, coding-style

I'm working on a project that requires us to be able to define a color scheme via a properties file post compile.

Currently we have a skin swc that defines our custom skins and have moved the color values to an actionscript file. This works well for centralizing the skin colors but doesn't allow us to change the values without recompiling.

I was thinking to use the ResoureManager for this task but we also have to support localization. As far as I know you can only specify one locale so we can't hack the ResourceManager for our purposes.

Anyone have an idea of how this can be accomplished?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your color scheme in a style sheet and load it at runtime.
So when you change you stylesheet, you odon't recompile your application, only the style sheet.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f8c.html